# Find $P (\min\{X, Y\} < x)$, for a given positive integer $x$: How to solve the series for solution?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

I have the following problem:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables taking values in the positive integers and having the same mass function $P(X = k) = P(Y = k) = 2^{−k}$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots$
>
> Find $P (\min\{X, Y\} < x)$, for a given positive integer $x$,

My solution is as follows:

$$\begin{align} P( \min\{X, Y\} < x ) &= 1 - P( \min\{X, Y\} > x ) \\ &= 1 - P(X > x, Y > y) \ \ \text{(Joint PMF.)} \\ &= 1 - P(X > x) P(Y > y) \ \ \text{(Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.)} \\ &= 1 - \sum_{k > x} 2^{-k} \sum_{k > y} 2^{-k} \ \ \text{(By the definition of PMF for $X$ and $Y$.)} \\ &= 1 - \left( \sum_{k > x} 2^{-k} \right)^2 \ \ \text{(Since $X$ and $Y$ have the same PMF.)} \\ &= 1 - \left( \sum_{k = x + 1} 2^{-k} \right)^2 \\ &= 1 - \left( \sum_{k' = 1} 2^{-(k' + x)} \right)^2 \ \ \text{(Define k' = k - x)} \\ &= 1 - \left( \sum_{k' = 1} 2^{-k' - x)} \right)^2 \\ &= 1 - 2^{-2x} \left( \sum_{k' = 1} 2^{-k'} \right)^2 \end{align}$$

I'm stuck here because I'm unsure of how to solve the series. The solution provided is the same as mine, but the author concludes that $1 - 2^{-2x} \left( \sum_{k' = 1} 2^{-k'} \right)^2 = 1 - 2^{-2x} = 1 - 1/4^x$. However, I'm unsure of what the author did here.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \sum\limits_{k'=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k'}=\frac {1/2} {1-1/2}=1$ by the formula for the sum of  a geometric series.

$ \sum\limits_{k'=1}^{\infty} r^{k'}=\frac r {1-r}$. Take $r=\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Where did your formula $\dfrac{r}{1 - r}$ come from? My textbook has the formula $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty ar^{n - 1} = \dfrac{a}{1 - r},$$ $|r| < 1$

Comment: @ThePointer In your formula take $a=1$ and then multiply both sides by $r$ to get my formula.

Comment: Ahh, ok, thanks.